# Why is the gradient of $f(x)= x$ the vector $(1,0,0)$?

Tags: vector-fields, slope

Why is the gradient of $f(x)= x$ the vector $(1,0,0)$? This would mean that at every point on the straight line $y = x$, I should go horizontally to experience the maximum change in slope. I was expecting the gradient at $(x,y)$ to be the the position vector of $(x,y)$ as it makes more sense. How does it make sense that the maximum change in slope will be attained by trying to move horizontally?

Comment: Gradient at $x$? At $(x,y)$? At $(x,y,z)$? What do you mean, really?

Comment: @HansLundmark The gradient in the xy plane of the straight line y = x

Comment: Then it seems as if you're confusing the phrase *gradient of a line* (= the line's slope, just a number) with the word *gradient* meaning the *gradient vector field* of a function of several variables. Same word, two different (although somewhat related) meanings.

Comment: @HansLundmark No, Im talking about the gradient vector only.

Comment: @HansLundmark We can also define a gradient vector for a single variable function right?

Comment: Well, that's confused too. Talking about the gradient vector of a **line** makes little sense. The gradient vector is something associated with a **function**.

Comment: The gradient vector of a function $f(x)$ is a vector with just one component, $(f'(x))$. So it lives on the $x$-line, not in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @HansLundmark So, the gradient vector of a single variable function gives us a vector which doesnt really point towards the direction of greatest change as is the case with multi variable functions?

Comment: Yes, it **does** point in the direction of greatest change, **along the $x$-line**! If $f'(x)>0$, move right in order to increase $f(x)$, if $f'(x)<0$, move to the left.

Comment: Just as the gradient of a two-variable function $f(x,y)$ points in the direction of greatest change in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh finally get it! Thanks for your perseverance :)

Comment: Great! Happy to help. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gradient of $f(x)=x$ is *not* $(1,0,0)$. It's just $1$, which means if you want to move in the direction of greatest increase of $f$, you should move in the $+1$ direction on the $x$-axis.

The gradient of $f(x,y,z)=x$ *is* $(1,0,0)$. This function has domain $\mathbb{R}^3$, so its graph is in $4$-dimensional space (making it difficult to picture). You can imagine it as placing a "label" at every point $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ where the label says the point's $x$-value. If we want to move in the direction of maximum increase of the labels, we should move in the $(1,0,0)$ direction (i.e., in the positive $x$-direction).

Comment: Ok I got my gradient wrong. But isn't the gradient of f = df/dx i + df/dy j + df/dz k ? Therefore the gradient should be i. What am i doing wrong here? Pls note Im new to this :)

Comment: That formula is true if $f$ is a function of three variables, e.g., $f(x,y,z)=x$. But you wrote $f(x)=x$, which is a function of one variable.

Comment: In general, if $f$ is a function of $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$, then the gradient of $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is $(\partial f/\partial x_1,\dots,\partial f/\partial x_n)$. In particular, the gradient of $f(x)$ is just $\text{d}f/\text{d}x$.

Comment: So the gradient of f(x) will not be a vector? I have solved problems where the gradient of f(x,y) is a vector

Comment: You could say it is a vector with one component, but usually people think of those as just numbers. The gradient of $f(x,y)$ *will* be a vector though because it is a function of two variables, and thus the gradient has two components.